# How to display subcategories from entity?

Tags: php, symfony

I have two entities: Supplier and Category joined ManyToMany.

Next, I have a form builder class where I add `EntityType::class`.

Category structure:

```
id, categoryName, parentId - where parentIds value can be:
0 - head category
1 - subcategory
etc
```

I need to display (in twig template) categories with structure:

```
Category1
    Subcategory1
    Subcategory2
Category2
    Subcategory3
    Subcategory4
```

etc. where Category are some kind of header and subcategory are checkboxes.

Please somebody give me a tip how to do this.

Comment: So only sub-categories are attached to suppliers?

Comment: Category with structure like this:(parentId determine if category is head category or subcategory)
id, categoryName, parentId - where parentIds value can be:
0 - head category
1 - subcategory
etc.

Comment: So how should I react to that? You post a question, I try to get further information, you answer by repeating the same information from question. Help me help you...

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question because of my english. If i understand, the answer is: no, category and subcategory are attached to suppliers :)

Comment: I was trying to clarify this statement: *"etc. where Category are some kind of header and subcategory are checkboxes."* E.g. `Category1` would be a category with `parentId=0` and `Subcategory1/2` with `parentId=1`? And you're stating that only *subcategory are checkboxes* while the others are *some kind of header*. With this in mind, I'm wondering why you would attach "head categories" to suppliers. It seems unnecessary. That said, can you add the `buildForm` method of `EntityType`. Or at least the relevant parts.

Comment: I try to do this in many ways. And I am lost. Let me ask you another question: I need to register supplier with some categories. Every supplier has few sub-categories from few head-categories. I want to display this in form as a checkboxes for sub-categories and header for head-categories. Ofcourse if user check few checkboxes(sub-categories) I need to write to database also head-categories of that sub-categories. How to do this?

Comment: Will you ever have more than one nested level of categories (e.g. sub-sub-categories)? I'm asking because, if not, then you could refactor that entity, which would result in a much easier handling in the form. But for now, I think you should reconsider assigning head-categories to suppliers. This is *implicit knowledge* because it's deducible from the assigned sub-categories.

Comment: probably no....

Comment: In the future please try to write your question using [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

Building on what we discussed in the comments, the following worked in my test environment:

**In`SupplierType::buildForm`**:

```
->add('categories', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => Category::class,
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    'group_by' => 'parent',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true
])
```

Though without form customization this would only render the checkboxes without headers. This is discussed here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5489#issuecomment-194943922

Implementing the fix by [MaxE17677](https://github.com/MaxE17677) the view would look *something* like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{# @see: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5489#issuecomment-194943922 #}
{%- block choice_widget_expanded -%}
     <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% for name, choices in form.vars.choices %}
            {% if choices is iterable  %}
                <label class="choice_category">
                    <strong>
                        {{ choice_translation_domain is same as(false) ? name : name|trans({}, choice_translation_domain) }}
                    </strong>
                </label>
                <div>
                    {% for key,choice in choices %}
                        {{ form_widget(form[key]) }}
                        {{ form_label(form[key]) }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                {{- form_widget(form[name]) -}}
                {{- form_label(form[name], null, {translation_domain: choice_translation_domain}) -}}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
{%- endblock choice_widget_expanded -%}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
            {{ form_row(form.categories) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

---

**Preview**:

[image: Preview]

---

The crucial thing is that you use [`group_by`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#group-by) feature of the `ChoiceType`. To get this to work with your current entities you might need to also use the [`query_builder`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) setting of `EntityType`. Something like:

```
// ...
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.parentId = 1')
    ;
},
```

along with:

```
// ...
'group_by' => function ($category) {
  // *pseudo-code*
  return $category->getParent()->getName();
}
```

Comment: I am going to check this in few hours, but i feel it help me a lot. thank you Yoshi.